# How to render Json data which is Needed

Tags: json, grails, gsp

```
[ {name: "name1", y: val1},
  {name: "name2", y: val2},
  {name: "name3", y: val3},
  ...,
  {name: "nameN", y: valN}
  ]
```

I would like to get value in this `JSON` format

**How to use this** format in `piechart` in `grails`?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the values in a Hash and the use render as JSON.

```
def getOrganizationGroups() {
    def result =  GroupType.findAll().sort({it.sortOrder}).collect() {
        [
                code: it.groupTypeCode,
                name: it.displayName,
                sort: it.sortOrder
        ]
    }
    render(result as JSON)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
```

def getData = Highchart.findAll() //Highchart domain name
HashMap map = new HashMap();
map.put(getData.name,getData.data);``
output:{"[dari, anand]":[5,6]}